# Output wont display properly for resultant matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, computation

I wrote this program to add two 3x3 matrices; can someone tell me why my output is yielding 2 resultant matrices???

```
package programExam;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class progEx {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = 3;

        //get the users input and store it in the two arrays
        System.out.println("\nEnter matrix1: \n");

        //declare 2 array with the appropriate number of rows
        //and columns in them to store the numbers in each matrix.
        //this is the first one.
        double[][]matrix1 = new double[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i< matrix1.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j< matrix1[i].length; j++){
                matrix1[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        //get the users input and store it in the two arrays
        System.out.println("\nEnter matrix2: \n");


        double [][] matrix2 = new double [3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i< matrix1.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j< matrix1[i].length; j++){
                matrix2[i][j]= input.nextDouble();
            }


        }
        //call the addMatrix method and pass it the two arrays
        System.out.println("The addition of the matrices is: ");

        double[][] resultingMatrix = addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2);



    }//end of main method


    //write the addMatrix method to add the two matrices and display the result

    public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] m1, double[][] m2){

        double[][] result = new double[m1.length][m1[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++){
                result[i][j]= m1[i][j] += m2[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1[0].length; j++) {
             System.out.print("  " + m1[i][j]);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + result[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    return result;
    }//end of add matrices

    //end of class  
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter matrix1: 

4 5 1 
4 3 2
6 3 9

Enter matrix2: 

9 2 4
7 4 2 
1 7 5

The addition of the matrices is: 

13.0  7.0  5.0  13.0  7.0  5.0
11.0  7.0  4.0  11.0  7.0  4.0
7.0  10.0  14.0  7.0  10.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have two `System.out.print` commands in your `addMatrix()` function.

I believe that this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1[0].length; j++) {
         System.out.print("  " + m1[i][j]);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("  " + result[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Should be simply:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("  " + result[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Also, note that you are modifying the matrix `m1` in that same function (inadvertently, I believe). Seems to me that this line:

```
result[i][j]= m1[i][j] += m2[i][j];
```

Should be

```
result[i][j]= m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
```

(note that `+=` was replaced by `+`)

Comment: I accepted it; sorry im very new to this @Andre Neves